# что надо исправить чтобы работала DATE?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql

```css
DECLARE
  TYPE FBS_PRACTIK_REC IS RECORD 
  (
   PROPERTY_CODE varchar2 (50),
   VALUE         varchar2 (320),
   **CREATED_DATA  date,  ---- Здесь проблема**
   ORDER_BY      NUMBER   
  );
  --
  TYPE t_tab  IS TABLE OF FBS_PRACTIK_REC index by binary_integer;
  l_tab t_tab;
  --
BEGIN 
   l_tab(1).PROPERTY_CODE := 'CERTIFICATES_TYPE';
   l_tab(1).VALUE         := 'REGISTRATION';
   l_tab(1).CREATED_DATA  := '25.12.2017 09:25:21';
   l_tab(1).ORDER_BY      := '1';
  
  FOR i IN 1..l_tab.count 
  loop  
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(i).PROPERTY_CODE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(i).VALUE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(i).CREATED_DATA);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_tab(i).ORDER_BY);         
                    
  END LOOP;
  null;
END;
```

есль в место **DATE** поставить **VARCHAR2 (50)**  всео работает, но мне нужно чтобы заработала с **DATE**

Comment: Литерал `'25.12.2017 09:25:21'` - имеет строковой тип, сконвертируйте его в дату: `to_date('25.12.2017 09:25:21', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mm:ss')`

Comment: спасибо, а он не правилно выводит

Comment: вывод и хранение - это разные вещи. Если надо выводить в определенном формате можно настроить "NLS_DATE_FORMAT" или преобразовать дату в строку при помощи `to_char()` ...

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(l_tab(i).CREATED_DATA, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

Comment: а как ичо и number работал to_number('16.66','99.99') ,  и вместо точке рабол и с запетой ?

Comment: я думаю стоит задать отдельный вопрос с примерами входных строк...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75551/discussion-between-kapcan-88-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо явно указать тип данных. В ДАТУ пишем ДАТУ:

```
l_tab(1).CREATED_DATA  := TO_DATE('25.12.2017 09:25:21','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

PS
для записи в поле с типом NUMBER можно и даже нужно описывать маску.

```
to_number('16.66','99D99')
```

а точку или запятую, как десячитный разделитель можно указать либо параметрах сессии:

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='. ';
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=', ';
```

либо в маске:

```
to_number('16.66','99D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''. ''')
to_number('16.66','99D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '', ''')
```

Comment: А для тех "месье, что знают толк в извращениях" можно написать выбор десятичного разделителя в динамике
`l_tab(1).ORDER_BY      := 'to_number('16.66','99D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '''||
case
  when instr(some_char,',') >0 then ','
  when instr(some_char,'.') >0 then '.'
end||
' ''');`